Agarrar objetos glb usando los controles oculus en aframe
tengo el siguiente código, donde el objetivo es que el usuario pueda interactuar con las figuras geométricas y el glb usando los controles del oculus rift s. El problema es que las figuras si las puedo mover, pero el glb no, alguien puede ayudarme? muchas gracias
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Super-Hands</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.misc.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands@^3.0.3/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <!-- Carga del modelo GLB -->
      <a-asset-item id="modelo-glb" src="personaje1.glb"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity>
      <a-camera></a-camera>
      <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box" super-hands hand-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
      <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box" super-hands hand-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
   
    <a-box grabbable stretchable color="red" position="0 3 -1"></a-box>
    <a-box grabbable stretchable color="blue" position="2 3 -1"></a-box>
    <a-box grabbable stretchable color="yellow" position="0 0 -1"></a-box>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#modelo-glb" grabbable position="0 0 -1"></a-entity>
  
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>

